# how to use the graphviz mingle filter

Tags: graphviz

I think this filter could be very helpful to my graphs, since I often have A LOT of nodes, with bundles of edges often going in the same direction.
Unfortunately, apart from the announcement at http://www.graphviz.org/News.php mentioning that:

> This release includes a new (1.5) version of the xdot format
>   supporting inline text characteristics such as  and
>   version-specific output based on xdotversion. In addition, we
>   introduce mingle, a filter for edge bundling.

I didnt find anything else by googling - any hint about it?

Also, I see that it is an option for xdot - I only used fdp/sfdp/neato so far, to get as output a jpg image: how should procede starting from the graphviz-file if I want to use xdot and arrive to a jpg?

Comment: I have the same problem, any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I found this link:

http://www.graphviz.org/content/how-use-mingle-and-edgepaint

That suggests piping:

```
fdp input.gv | mingle | neato -Tpdf -o output.pdf
```

or
    dot input.dot | mingle | neato -Tpng -o out.png

However, I have not gotten this working on both windows and unix, as mingle apparently keeps (even for dummy graphs).